# How do I use Parallel.ForEachAsync in VB.NET using .NET 6?

Tags: vb.net, .net-6.0, parallel.foreach, parallel.foreachasync

.NET 6 introduced the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0) method which works pretty well in C#, but I'm running into issues using it in VB.NET.

Namely, the following example in C#:

```
using HttpClient client = new()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com"),
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("DotNet", "6"));
 
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
};
 
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(userHandlers, parallelOptions, async (uri, token) =>
{
    var user = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<GitHubUser>(uri, token);
 
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {user.Name}\nBio: {user.Bio}\n");
});
```

I cannot work out how to convert this section into VB.NET:

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(userHandlers, parallelOptions, async (uri, token) =>
    {
});
```

The most logical conversion I can think of is this:

```
Await Parallel.ForEachAsync(userHandlers, parallelOptions, Function(uri, token)
                                                           //stuff
                                                           End Function))
```

But that does not work, throwing an error `BC36532: Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'Func(Of String, cancellationToken, ValueTask)'`

I can appreciate that the method expects a `ValueTask` but I can't work out how to properly do that. Using a `Sub` instead of `Function` doesn't work either, neither does wrapping it all in a `Task`. There has to be something really dumb that I'm missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the use of `Parallel.ForEachAsync()` necessary? Can't you await `Task.WhenAll()` instead? -- I don't think the `Sub()` / `Function()` Lambda has been updated to support an awaitable `ValueTask`. You *could* return a `ValueTask`, removing `async` from the Lambda and unwrapping the Task *manually*.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so it was a Visual Studio glitch that persisted between restarts...

I did the following:

```
Await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Of String)(userHandlers, parallelOptions, New Func(Of String, CancellationToken, ValueTask) _
            (Function(uri, token)
```

Which worked, and then I removed the explicit stuff to get back to this:

```
 Await Parallel.ForEachAsync(userHandlers, parallelOptions, Function(uri, token)
```

Which is the exact function that didn't want to work before. Trying to make that nested function `Async` breaks it again with the same `BC36532` error, but not as "permanently" as before. Very weird.

It would seem that maybe VB.NET just doesn't have support for nested Async?

Comment: You might find [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-support-planned-for-net-5-0/ "Visual Basic support planned for .NET 5.0") interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything, so you need to use Sub instead of Function. VB.Net also has async anonymous methods similar to C#, but you must use the keywoard `Async` in front of it. Try this

```
Await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    userHandlers, 
    parallelOptions, 
    Async Sub(uri, token)
        //stuff
    End Sub))
```

For more, see [async modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/async)

Comment: I don't think that that will work because `Sub` will generate an `Action` delegate while `ForEachAsync` requires a `Func`.

Comment: I've been doing some testing and I can't find a combination that works.

Comment: Sub doesn’t work, unfortunately. I’m pretty good with using Async/Await, it’s just a struggle with this lambda expression in particular.